# Creating Database Values in a Rake Task - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I have the following script, which I want to automatically update my database.

```
require 'feedzirra'
require 'sanitize'

namespace :db do

  task :update_pitzer => :environment do

    feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse('http://www.cafebonappetit.com/rss/menu/219')

    feed.entries.each do |entry|
      date = Sanitize::clean(entry.title)
      summary = Sanitize::clean(entry.summary)
      summary.gsub!(/\s{2}/, " ").to_s
      summary.gsub!(/\s{2}/, "").to_s
      summary.gsub!("&amp;", "&")
      puts "#{date}"

      theDay = Day.create(date: date)
      #theDay.collins_meals.create()

      array = summary.split(/\[/)
      array.collect! {|x| "[" + x}
      array.reject! {|x| x == "[ "}
      array.to_s
      puts array
    end
  end
end
```

When I run rake db:update_pitzer at the command line, I get:

```
   (in /Users/Alex/rails_projects/dining_hall_api)
   rake aborted!
   Don't know how to build task 'db:update_pitzer'
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Just a suggestion - not sure if it's related - I think you shouldn't use :db as namespace for custom rake tasks as it is already defined somewhere else... I'm not sure you can extend it. Try to change the namespace to something like :populate in a "populate.rake" file in the "lib/tasks" folder, and then launch rake populate:update_pitzer. Does it throw the same error?

Comment: Namespace was the problem all along - doh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code seems proper. Make sure you have put 'update_pitzer.rb' file under 'lib/tasks' folder in your rails application